# Explanation related outer measure and measurable cover

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure, borel-measures

[image]

Theorem C is from the book Measure Theory by Halmos...from Chapter 3.

My question: how Sigma finite of E is used in the proof?

It will be very much helpful kindly give some hint or explanation.

Comment: What about the 2nd sentence of the proof, where $\sigma$-finite is brought up? Did you miss that?

Comment: I have noticed but I am unable to understand how we are using Sigma finiteness...though in the excercise Halmos has shown that it is necessary for the assumption. I think it is easy but maybe I am not getting it.